# intern running foo and bar tests without being called

Tags: intern

I have created automated tests for `intern (testing framework)`, whenever I run the test through `selenium-server` it runs a series of `foo` and `bar` unit tests that aren't in my testing directories. are these tests run from an intern or selenium directory? I have not been able to figure out how to stop or delete these tests. any suggestions?

this is my `intern.js` file which doesn't have any `suites` defined for unit tests:

```js
 /* Name of the tunnel class to use for WebDriver tests. */
 tunnel: "NullTunnel",
    
 loaderOptions: {
     /* Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment */
 },
    
 /* Unit test suite(s) to run in each browser */
    suites: [ /**/ ],

 /* Functional test suite(s) to execute against each browser once unit tests are completed */
 functionalSuites: [ "src/test/intern/integration/ITIndexHtml" ],

 /* A regular expression matching URLs to files that should not be included in code coverage analysis */
 excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests that are initially run during functional testing are feature tests. Browsers don't all have the same level of testing support, and sometimes they implement testing features slightly differently. Intern tests the remote browsers to determine what works and what doesn't, and then attempts to provide consistent behavior (consistent between different browsers) when possible.

Comment: so there is no way to turn the `feature tests` off? or have them run in the background where you cant see them run?

Comment: You can turn them off by setting `fixSessionCapabilities` to false in the `capabilities` property in your config (or in the environment object for a specific browser). However, turning them off may cause some feature degradation, depending on your target browser.